# Missing data for input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to build a model in TF2 which comprises of the following components: `MobilenetV2`, 2 layers of `BLSTM` and then a `CTC` attached to it. The following demonstrates the model:

```
def build_model():
    img_width = 200
    img_height = 50

    input_img = layers.Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3), name="input_1", dtype="float32")

    labels = layers.Input(name="label", shape=(None,), dtype="float32")

    base_model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(
        input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3),
        alpha=1.0,
        depth_multiplier=1,
        dropout=0.001,
        include_top=False,
        weights="imagenet",
        input_tensor=None,
        pooling=None,
        classes=1000,
        classifier_activation="softmax",
    )
    x = base_model.output
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(6,1024), name="reshape")(x)
    x = Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    x = Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25))(x)
    output = CTCLayer(name="ctc_loss")(labels, x)
    
    # Define the model
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=[base_model.input, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
    )
    # Optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    # Compile the model and return
    model.compile(optimizer=opt)
    return model
```

when I call the `build_model` function it throws the following error:

> ValueError: Missing data for input "input_1". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['image', 'label']. Expected the following keys: ['input_1', 'label']

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: The error is clear. Either rename `name="input_1"` to `name="image"`, or change your input key.